# AlwaysOn Async mode

Tags: availability-groups, disaster-recovery

I have forced manual failover AOAGs  to BCP node.I tested my application and data is reflecting in tables very late.Is it expected behavior or I need to take care of anything permissions,firewall ports etc...

One more thing,

After forced failover I bought the databases online by resume data movement but Replicas shows still in ? mode.How can I make them Online.

Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

Latency on the asynchronous replica will be dependent on lots of factors, such as size of the transactions (index rebuilds could cause a huge amount of backlog), I/O, network, etc. If you want zero latency, then you'll need to use synchronous and not asynchronous, but be aware that this adds to the transaction time and should be within the same data center as the primary replica (in general).

When you force failover, the AG replicas will need to be rebuilt with a full backup and log chain to get back in sync and rejoined to the AG.

Comment: When you force failover, the AG replicas will need to be rebuilt with a full backup and log chain to get back in sync and rejoined to the AG. --- @Tara when you say rebuilt using a full backup(Backups from former Primary replica which is in Sync? )

Comment: You should be able to use the backups from the former primary replica as it's all based on LSNs. Then just run a log backup on the primary and apply that to the secondary, then join to AG.